# Volley with post parameters and php json

Tags: android, android-volley

I followed the [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) tutorial to implement Volley. I created the two classes (AppController, LruBitmapCache).
I can make a basic query work, but when I am passing parameters, I get an error:

```
Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    jsonParams.put("city", "Wien");

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, list_all_users_json, new JSONObject(jsonParams), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("JSONJSONJSONJSON", response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("JSONJSONJSONJSON", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

    };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

PHP:

```
$city = $_POST['city'];

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT USERS.USERNAME       
    FROM USERS
    WHERE USERS.CITY=?");

    $stmt -> execute($city);        

        while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $output[] = $row;
            $response["success"] = 1;
        }


    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $response["success"] = 0;
    }

    $struct = array("Output" => $output);

print(json_encode($struct));
```

The error I get is:

```
01-16 22:59:59.817: D/Volley(31689): [1] 3.onErrorResponse: JSONJSONJSONJSON
```

I am ot a JSON guy so there's obviously something wrong with my code I just can't find out what it is.